# Extract elements from a list using indexes from another list using R

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list with collections of vectors and a second list (of the same length) of indexes. I'd like to use the second list to extract only the indexed elements of the first list.

```
dataList <- list(1:10, 101:150, LETTERS)
indexList <- list(3:5, 10:15, c(1,5,9,15,21))
```

i.e. I'd like a function to return a new list the same length as dataList, but containing only the members indexed by indexList.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` to extract the corresponding `list` elements based on the index from 'indexList'

```
Map(`[`, dataList, indexList)
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(dataList, indexList, `[`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lapply()

```
dataList <- list(1:10, 101:150, LETTERS)
indexList <- list(3:5, 10:15, c(1,5,9,15,21))
lapply(1:length(dataList), FUN=function(x, list1, list2) list1[[x]][list2[[x]]] , list1=dataList, list2=indexList)
```

Which gives:-

```
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 110 111 112 113 114 115

[[3]]
[1] "A" "E" "I" "O" "U"
```